# как написать более серьезную регулярку для слова да или нет?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

написал вот такую, но она пропускает лишнее слова

```
re_answer = re.compile(r"b\[д|н][а|е]+\b")
```

она пропускает слова дет нат итп, а нужно чтобы она после буквы д шла только буква а, а после н только буква е

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b(да)\b|\b(нет)\b`. Вроде максимально полно. Можно и без скобок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

```
r"\b(да|нет)\b"
```